# Two rules at the same time and their order

Tags: .htaccess

I have aim to use two domains (old and new). So when I go to address:
http://old.cz/whatever/whatever
I would like to get to:
http://new.cz/whatever/whatever

Perfectly works for me this thing:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.cz/$1 [R=301]
```

But! At the same time I want following. When I go to address:
http://old.cz/
I want to get to:
http://new.cz/specific-page/specific-page

For that works this code:

```
Redirect 301 / http://new.cz/specific-page/specific-page
```

My issue is that in case I use both rules at the same time the first one is always prioritize and the second one suppressed. It means that when I go to http://old.cz/ I always get on only to http://new.cz/

Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` and `RewriteRule` are directives of two different apache modules `mod-alias` and `mod-rewrite` . You can not combine these two directive for url redirection because of their different runtime behaviour.  Use RewriteRule  instead of Redirect.

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?$ http://new.cz/specific-page/specific-page [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.cz/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you!